# Set media files Title and Album in Background Audio in Windows Phone 8.1 Store apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

I am building a Windows Phone 8.1 RT App which runs MP3 files in Background task.

I followed the steps in the sample code shown here : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319

When the app runs in the background, I would like to show the Album Artist & Song Title. 
Currently it just shows the file name.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SampleBackgroundAudioTask, there is a MyBackgroundAudioTask which is the background audio task used for playing music. There's an object of type [SystemMediaTransportControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/Apps/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols) in that class called systemmediatransportcontrol.

[SystemMediaTransportControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn263187.aspx) class enables your app to use the system media transport controls provided by Windows and update the media info that is displayed. There's a private method in MyBackgroundAudioTask responsible for updating the UVC (Universal Volume Control) when current track changes called UpdateUVCOnNewTrack. This uses the [SystemMediaTransportControls.DisplayUpdater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/Apps/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols.displayupdater) to set the [MusicProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/Apps/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrolsdisplayupdater.musicproperties). MusicProperties is of type [MusicDisplayProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/Apps/windows.media.musicdisplayproperties) and include properties such as the song title and the song artist.

This is how you set the song title and artist which gets shown in the UVC.

```
systemmediatransportcontrol.DisplayUpdater.MusicProperties.Title = "My lovely track";
systemmediatransportcontrol.DisplayUpdater.MusicProperties.Artist = "An awesome artist";
systemmediatransportcontrol.DisplayUpdater.Update();
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the Media tags directly from the MP3 file, instead of having to explicitly setting it?

Comment: Your answer works, but just wondering if I could be picked up from the tags defined on my MP3 file so I don't have to worry about setting it.

Comment: @SaqibVaid I think there's a way to read MusicProperties from a file - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.musicproperties

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that I could something like StorageFile storageFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Media\XYZ.mp3"); //Get file name here
            await systemmediatransportcontrol.DisplayUpdater.CopyFromFileAsync(MediaPlaybackType.Music, storageFile);
            systemmediatransportcontrol.DisplayUpdater.Update();

Comment: is it possible to sett the values from the foreground app. because i am trying but isn't working ?